# How to Update SharePoint List Items without Creating New Versions

Tags: powershell, versioning

Actually I'm working on PowerShell script using that I'm trying to update list item **Modified By** and **Modified** filed value without changing version.

Is it possible to do that using PoweShell ?

Please suggest some script

Comment: How about turning the versioing off on the list before the script starts the modification process and have it turned on at the end once processing is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the item as below:

`item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();`

UpdateOverwriteVersion()

1. No new version.
2. Updates the item without creating a new version of the item
3. Updates the modified time and modified by fields

Answer (score 0):

You should be updating the item with : `item.SystemUpdate($false);`

Comment: item.SystemUpdate($false); will not stop changing item version

Comment: @AkshayDattatrayNangare : Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms481195.aspx  You should pass $false parameter to keep the version.