# Unlike what is mentioned on many articles, using SystemUpdate() is able to our enterprise wiki pages without creating new versions

Tags: 2013, development, powershell

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection inside sharepoint on-premises 2013, and i want to update a field named "PageNumber", without affecting the modified, modifedby & version number, so i wrote this powershell script and i run it inside a test wiki site:-

```
$site = get-SPWeb http://**/site/customerwiki/
#specify the list name 
$list = $site.Lists["Customer KB"] 
$listitems = $list.Items 

foreach ($listitem in $listitems) 
{ 
    write-host $listitem["ID"] "processed"
    $listitem["PageNumber"] = $listitem["Initial"]+$listitem["ID"];
    $listitem.SystemUpdate()
    write-host $listitem["Name"] "has been updated." 

}
```

where the wiki pages got updated without creating new version or update the modified-by or modified date.. now i am asking this question as i found many articles which mentioned that suing `SystemUpdate()` will create new versions such as this link:- [How to Update SharePoint List Items without Creating New Versions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203516/how-to-update-sharepoint-list-items-without-creating-new-versions)

so can anyone advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.SystemUpdate(false)` which will not create a new version.

[SPListItem.SystemUpdate Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate?view=sharepoint-server)

Comment: Hehe, I thought OP was asking how to make sure it _does_ create a new version.

Comment: @Trevor Seward but in my case if  i use `.SystemUpdate() ` without passing any parameters will not create  new version as well,,, so is my approach f using `.SystemUpdate() ` without passing any parameters a valid appraoch as well? i got confused as a lot of articles mentioned that using Systemupdate() (without any parameters) will create a new version.. but based on my test it will not

Answer (score 1):

**SystemUpdate()** is the same as **SystemUpdate(false)**

**SPListItem.SystemUpdate method**

> Calling this method is the same as calling SystemUpdate(Boolean) with false.

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms461526(v%3Doffice.15)).
I might be a bit old fashioned, but what is wrong with checking the official documentation? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `true` as a parameter in order for it to increment the version number:

```
$listitem.SystemUpdate($true)
```

[MSDN documentation on `SystemUpdate()`.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate?view=sharepoint-server)

Comment: now i do not want the `SystemUpdate()` to create a new version,, and my script is being able to do so,, but i got confused as a lot of articles mentioned that using `Systemupdate()` (without any parameters) will create a new version.. i hope i have explained my question better..

Comment: If you do _not_ want a new version, then Trevor Seward's answer is the correct one.

Comment: yes i do NOT want to create new version, and based on my test using Systemupdate() (without any parameters) will NOT create new version.. or i have to pass `false` parameter??

Comment: If through your testing you have found that passing no parameters results in no new version, I would say that seems like a perfectly valid approach.  However, it might be a little bit safer to pass `$false` as a parameter to explicitly tell SharePoint "no, I do _not_ want a new version."  That way there is no question what you are telling SharePoint to do.